# Primefaces dataTable filter on enter

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, filter, datatable

I am using primefaces 5.0 and datatable with filter option. But it is unconvenient to type one letter and wait when it is will filter and update then type next letter. It is also slows a server. Therefore there is need for press enter key after you fill filter option and then filter.

There was filterDelay option in primefaces 3.5 but I dont see in primefaces 5.

I used to hack by javascript code as follows

```
$('th .ui-column-filter').each(function() {
                        var inp = $(this);
                        inp.unbind('keydown');
                        inp.unbind('keyup');
                        inp.unbind('keypress');
                        inp.keypress(function(event) {
                            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                                alert("entered");
                                event.stopPropagation();
                                gwsReportAllPartListDataTable.filter();
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                    });
```

Well, it did not work.

How can I do it with primefaces 5?

Comment: Do you have more than one filter option on your table? You could combine primefaces' hotkey and the globalFilter attribute to filter on return

Comment: Yes. there 19 filters above 19 columns. I have refused to use filters. Many things are out of control. So, just added inputText into column headers and made hidden button to submit when user presses enter key in intputtext.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the PrimeFaces User Guide (5.0 and 5.1), there still is the option filterEvent="..." and also filterDelay="..."

> Name: *filterEvent*, Default: *keyup*, Type: *String*, Description: *Event to invoke filtering for input filters*.
>   Name: *filterDelay*, Default: *300*, Type: *Integer*, Description: *Delay in milliseconds before sending an ajax filter query.*

Both options are for the tag *p:dataTable*

One of these two should solve your problem, I guess. (the Delay option, if you were willing to change to filters on the columns, or on the other hand the filterEvent option, which is still existent).

Answer (score 1):

In the [5.2 Userguide (Chapter 3.32)](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_1.pdf) there is still a *filterDelay* option in the *DataTable*. Doesn't it work for you?

A very similar solution to your was posted by BalusC in his blog "[How to filter p:dataTable on enter event](http://ovaraksin.blogspot.de/2011/04/how-to-filter-pdatatable-on-enter-event.html)" from April 7, 2011. Maybe you can adapt something from there.

Comment: You linked to [a blog by Oleg Varaksin](http://ovaraksin.blogspot.de/2011/04/how-to-filter-pdatatable-on-enter-event.html) as BalusC's. Did you read the blog?

Comment: Well, this post is old and many new versions with much modificaitons were out after this post. There is no filterEvent option anymore. Thank you :)

Answer (score -3):

For the angular 2+ users out there what you can do is instead of doing(using the example from https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/filter):

```
<input *ngSwitchCase="'vin'" pInputText type="text" (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, col.field, col.filterMatchMode)">
```

You can do:

```
<input *ngSwitchCase="'vin'" pInputText type="text" (keyup.enter)="dt.filter($event.target.value, col.field, col.filterMatchMode)">
```

Comment: This question is about PrImeFaces, not PrimeNG